# List comparison of element

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a question and it is a bit hard for me to explain so I will be using lots of examples to help you all understand and see if you could help me.

Say I have two lists containing book names from best to worst rated by two people. User1 rated `lstA`, and user2 rated `lstB`

```
lstA = ['Harry Potter','1984','50 Shades','Dracula']
lstB = ['50 Shades','Dracula','1984','Harry Potter']
```

User one thinks 'Harry Potter' is better than 'Dracula' (HP is index 0, and Dracula is index 3)

User two thinks 'Harry Potter' is worse than Dracula, (HP is index 3 and Dracula is index 1)

In this case, return a tuple `('Harry Potter', 'Dracula')` [`('Dracula', 'Harry Potter')` is also fine]

User one also rated '50 shades' better than 'Dracula' and user two also rated '50 shades' better than 'Dracula' (index 2, 3 and 0, 1 respectively). In this case, nothing happens.

The final result of the program should return a list of tuples so,

```
[('Harry Potter','50 Shades'), ('Harry Potter','Dracula'), ('Harry Potter','1984'), ('1984', '50 Shades'), ('1984','Dracula')]
```

Could someone help me to point me in the right direction to come up with an algorithm that gives all the tuples?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/ It does precisely what you are looking for.

Comment: It appears that you have a habit of not selecting answers. You will gain some reputation for each answer you select, and your question will have a canonical answer for future readers. Please select answers when they help you.

Answer (score 4):

First formulate your logic mathematically. For all *combinations* of length 2, given indices `idx_a1, idx_a2` and `idx_b1, idx_b2`, if `sign(idx_a1 - idx_a2) != sign(idx_b1 - idx_b2)`, record the combination.

The below isn't efficient, but it shows one way of transforming this logic to code:

```
from itertools import combinations

lstA = ['Harry Potter','1984','50 Shades','Dracula']
lstB = ['50 Shades','Dracula','1984','Harry Potter']

def sign(x):
    """Return +1 if integer is positive, -1 if negative"""
    return (x > 0) - (x < 0)

res = []
for a, b in combinations(lstA, 2):
    idx_a1, idx_a2 = lstA.index(a), lstA.index(b)
    idx_b1, idx_b2 = lstB.index(a), lstB.index(b)
    if sign(idx_a1 - idx_a2) != sign(idx_b1 - idx_b2):
        res.append((a, b))

[('Harry Potter', '1984'),
 ('Harry Potter', '50 Shades'),
 ('Harry Potter', 'Dracula'),
 ('1984', '50 Shades'),
 ('1984', 'Dracula')]
```

Comment: I think I found a way without using the indices at all.

Comment: Hello, I am not too familiar with "from itertools import combinations" could you explain how that function works? Currently, I am writing using nested for loops but cant quite get the results yet.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to accumulate all the positive orderings form each list into a set, then take the difference of the two sets. The positive ordering would be `(a, b)` when the `a` precedes `b` in its respective list. This is the ordering guaranteed by [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
from itertools import combinations

setA = set(combinations(lstA, 2))
setB = set(combinations(lstB, 2))

result = setA - setB
```

This would simply discard any orderings that the two sets agree on. If both lists had the same books, this would be almost identical to

```
result = setB - setA
```

The only difference would be that all the tuples would be reversed.

If you had different books in each list, you would need to add a couple of extra steps to clean up the duplicates and combine the two sets:

```
resultA = setA - setB
resultB = setB.difference(x[::-1] for x in setA)
result = resultA | resultB
```

The first step computes all the elements from `lstA` that `lstB` does not agree with. The next step finds the elements of `lstB` that aren't reversed versions of what we have in `resultA`, since the disagreements over books in both lists are guaranteed to be reversed in the sets. I used the method [`set.difference`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) here in preference to the `-` operator because that way there is no need to create a set object from the generator expression. You can't just use [`symmetric_difference`/`^`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) unfortunately because the elements are reversed. The third step just computes the union of the results.

IDEOne Link: https://ideone.com/DuHTed. This demos both the original case in the question and the asymmetric lists.

Comment: Nice! Although is it guaranteed that all orderings you generate with `combinations(lstA, 2)` will be "positive orderings"?

Comment: @slider. Yes, that's what the docs seem to be guaranteeing (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), and this confirms: https://ideone.com/dExkt4

Comment: Great. Based on that, I think I can simplify mine too a little bit more.

Comment: I still don't get *Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.* Clearly the list here is not sorted in "lexicographic sort order", which from what I understand means alphabetical order.

Comment: @slider. I think that the key is the next paragraph: *Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value.*. In that sense, it's lexicographically sorted when you think only of the indices. I'm not sure enough, so I'll ask a question momentarily.

Comment: @slider: hope someone clears this up for us https://stackoverflow.com/q/53112861/2988730

Answer (score 2):

An efficient version of @jpp's solution is as follows:

```
from itertools import combinations

lstA = ['Harry Potter','1984','50 Shades','Dracula']
lstB = ['50 Shades','Dracula','1984','Harry Potter']

bIndices = {b: i for i, b in enumerate(lstB)}
aPairs = [sorted(c) for c in combinations(enumerate(lstA), 2)]

mismatches = [(book1[1], book2[1]) for book1, book2 in aPairs if bIndices[book1[1]] > bIndices[book2[1]]]
print(mismatches)
# [('Harry Potter', '1984'), ('Harry Potter', '50 Shades'), ('Harry Potter', 'Dracula'), ('1984', '50 Shades'), ('1984', 'Dracula')]
```

Note that `aPairs` are combinations of (index, book) tuples and each combination is sorted by the index which guarantees that in each pair of books, the first is "better" than the next (for user A).

Now to compute ordering mismatches, we just need to decide whether the corresponding book indices in `lstB` also preserve this ordering.

#### Edit

As @MadPhysicist noted, `combinations` preserves the original order in the array in each generated tuple, so no need to create `aPairs` as a list of sorted `(index, book)` tuples. We can directly generate `mismatches` with just `bIndices`:

```
lstA = ['Harry Potter','1984','50 Shades','Dracula']
lstB = ['50 Shades','Dracula','1984','Harry Potter']

bIndices = {b: i for i, b in enumerate(lstB)}
mismatches = [(book1, book2) for book1, book2 in combinations(lstA, 2) if bIndices[book1] > bIndices[book2]]
```

Comment: I think my way may be even further cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iter` and then compare indices

```
res = []  

for i in lstA:
    a = iter(lstB)
    while True:
        try:
            b = next(a)
            if lstA.index(i) < lstA.index(b) and lstB.index(i) > lstB.index(b):
                res.append((i, b))
        except StopIteration:
            break 

print(res)
# [('Harry Potter', '50 Shades'), ('Harry Potter', 'Dracula'), ('Harry Potter', '1984'), ('1984', '50 Shades'), ('1984', 'Dracula')]
```

Comment: This seems awfully inefficient compared to the other answers, but is probably easier to understand.

Comment: @MadPhysicist How would this be less efficient, other methods are creating extra wasted combinations then filtering through them, this only creates one list of only pairs that will be used

Comment: You're doing a linear search for each element in both lists for one thing. For example, you could use `enumerate` in your outer loop to avoid `lstA.index(i)`. Your algorithm probably does indeed save a fraction of the space, but at the cost of a dramatic increase in time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist hmm yeah I guess, Just this same type of problem was at hand before and I used `combination`s disgarding the unused and was made a point of by MartijnPeters about how inefficient it can be do create all sorts of combinations just to filter a few out