# What is the guarantee made by itertools.combinations?

Tags: python

The docs for [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) state:

> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input *iterable* is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.
>
> **Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value.** So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each combination.

[Emphasis mine]

What is the exact guarantee being made here? An empirical check shows that elements are always emitted as if by

```
for i in range(len(iterable)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(iterable)):
        for k in range(j + 1, len(iterable)):
            ...
                yield iterable[i], iterable[j], iterable[k], ...
```

What is the meaning of "lexicographixal order" in this case? In particular, I believe that the emphasized sentence is crucial, but I am not 100% of what the connection is. I *think* it means that the lexicographixal order is applied to the indices of the elements regardless of value, but I'd love to have someone confirm that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order ;  tl;dr, if you start with "abc", you will be getting "ab", "ac, "bc", and not "ba", "bc", "ac", for example (which would be the output of 2-combinations of "bac"). tl;dr of tl;dr: your loops.

Comment: @Amadan. I'm aware of what lexicographixal order is and what combinations outputs. I'm just perplexed by parsing those particular paragraphs properly. Perhaps I'm overthinking it...

Comment: @Amadan my problem is specifically that it's not clear to me that the emphasized line has anything to do with the paragraph that precedes it.

Comment: Probably not, no. That's why they're separate paragraphs. The first paragraph talks about the order in which elements will be output, the second paragraph talks about the possible combinations that will appear.

Comment: @deceze. If you're correct, I'm even more confused.

Comment: Ah. "lexicographical order" has a mathematical and linguistic meaning. Mathematical is what Python does, where `combinations("bac", 2)` yields "ba", "bc", "ac". The other meaning would be real alphabetic ordering, where no matter in which order the iterator yields its elements, the result is generated in the order you'd find in a dictionary: "ab", "ac", "bc" - lexicographic ordering based on the value of "a" < "b" < "c", not based on position "b" < "a" < "c".

Comment: @Amadan If we start with "cba", we get "cb", "ca", "ba". But "cba" isn't "lexicographically" ordered. So now what is the guarantee (will the combinations preserve the original ordering in the list)?

Comment: The second paragraph _is_ a bit weird, because the guarantee is actually looser than if it it was by value. `combinations("aab", 2) yields "aa", "ab", "ab", treating each "a" as distinct because it has a different position. If it did not, you'd only get two outputs, `aa` and `ab`.

Comment: @slider Lexicographic does not mean *alphabetically* here. It basically just means "in whatever order the input was supplied in"; the input here being the "lexicon" which defines the order.

Comment: @Amadan to add to slider's point, this question arose because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53112472/2988730

Comment: @wim. Any comment? You seem very well versed in issues like this.

Comment: "In that sense, it's lexicographically sorted when you think only of the indices" - yes, this is exactly what is meant here. Lexicographic ordering of a combination is defined by the order of the original set, as deceze says, not by alphabet. A lexicographical ordering of a dictionary is always based on alphabet (for English, anyway); here, we get to define our own order, and `combinations` will be produced in accordance to this order. If the iteratee is in alphabetical order, then the output will also be in alphabetical order. If the iteratee is in reverse alphabetical order, so will output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To translate these paragraphs from computer sciencese into English:

> Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.

"Lexicographic" here is a mathematical term and does not mean *alphabetically*, but "in whatever order the lexicon defines".

> early 17th century: modern Latin, from Greek *lexikon (biblion)* ‘(book) of words’, from *lexis* ‘word’, from *legein* ‘speak’.

The "lexicon" here being your input. Put plainly, your input defines the order in which the output will be produced. If you want alphabetically sorted output, sort your input.

> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each combination.

This just says that `combinations` will not look at or care about the actual values themselves, it just combines elements by their position. It won't deduplicate based on the values, it deduplicates combinations of positions. If you want unique combinations, deduplicate your input.

Comment: "The "lexicon" here being your input." Was the missing link. It all makes sense now. Thanks.